# How to cancel UIView block-based animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, ios4, uiimageview

I've searched loads of SO stuff and in Apple's references, but still unable to manage my problem.

### What I have:

1. A screen with 2 `UIImageView`s and 2 `UIButton`s connected to them
2. 2 kinds of animation:

   1. Scaling up and then down of each image, one after another, only once in `viewDidLoad`
   2. When a button pressed (a custom button hidden 'inside' of each `UIImageView`) it triggers animation of appropriate `UIImageView`–only one, not both–(also scale up, then down).
   3. As I am writing for iOS4+ I'm told to use block based animations!

### What I need:

How do I cancel a running animation? I've managed to cancel after all but the last one... :/

Here is my code snippet:

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 
                               delay:0.1 
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                          animations:^{
        isAnimating = YES;
        self.bigLetter.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.bigLetter.transform, 2.0, 2.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if(! finished) return;
        [UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 
                                   delay:0.0 
                                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                              animations:^{
            self.bigLetter.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.bigLetter.transform, 0.5, 0.5);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            if(! finished) return;
            [UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 
                                       delay:0.0 
                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                                  animations:^{
                self.smallLetter.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.smallLetter.transform, 2.0, 2.0);
            } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                if(! finished) return;
                [UIImageView animateWithDuration:2.0 
                                           delay:0.0 
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                                      animations:^{
                    self.smallLetter.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.smallLetter.transform, 0.5, 0.5);
                }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                          if (!finished) return;
                                          //block letter buttons
                                          [self.bigLetterButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                                          [self.smallLetterButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                                          //NSLog(@"vieDidLoad animations finished");
                                      }];
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

Somehow the `smallLetter` `UIImageView` is not working properly, because when pressed (through button) `bigLetter` is canceling animations properly...

**EDIT:**
I've used this solution, but still having problem with scaling down `smallLetter` `UIImageView` - not cancelling at all...
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190197/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-a-chain-of-block-based-animations)

**EDIT2:** I've added this at the beginning of next/prev methods:

```
- (void)stopAnimation:(UIImageView*)source {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations:^ {
                         source.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     }
                     completion:NULL
     ];
}
```

problem stays... :/ no idea how to interrupt last animation for letters in animation chain

Comment: Hey I think Hari Kunwar's answer should be accepted now.

Comment: These days you ***must*** use UIViewPropertyAnimator - it's tremendously easier, also.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can stop all animations on a view by calling:

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

(You'll need to import the QuartzCore framework to call methods on view.layer).

If you want to stop a specific animation, not all animations, your best best bet is to use CAAnimations explicitly rather than the UIView animation helper methods, then you will have more granular control and can stop animations explicitly by name.

The Apple Core Animation documentation can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Comment: Just want to add, in my own observation, subsequent animateWithDuration doesn't work anymore after calling removeAllAnimations. This is for doing pagination and pull to refresh controls, perhaps someone else might observe something different. I end up using CABasicAnimation and calling [myView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animationKey"];

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Nick - just a heads up that the link no longer seems to be supported, try this one instead: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Comment: after view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
add animate view again not working

Answer (score 72):

For iOS 10 use UIViewPropertyAnimator to animate. 
It provides methods to start, stop and pause UIView animations.

```
 let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2.0, curve: .easeOut){
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
 }
 // Call this to start animation.
 animator.startAnimation()

 // Call this to stop animation.
 animator.stopAnimation(true)
```

Comment: Adding a comment to catch your eye, extremely relevant answer for newer code

Answer (score 4):

I'd add to Nick's answer that to make removeAllAnimations smooth next idea be very handy.

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.redView
                  duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                      [view.layer displayIfNeeded];
                  } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (in Swift):

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

Note: you can put code between those two calls if necessary, for example:

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
aview.layer.removeAllAnimations() // remove layer based animations e.g. aview.layer.opacity
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```