# cancel a UIView animateWithDuration before completion

Tags: ios, uiview, uianimation, quartz-core

I have this code in my project:

```
- (void) fadeImageView {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //make the image view un-tappable.
                         //if the fade was canceled, set the alpha to 1.0
                     }];

}
```

however, there are circumstance where i would like to cancel this operation before the imageview has become invisible. Is there a way to cancel this animation mid animation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel a UIView animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation)  Sure it's not block based, but it works.

Comment: Note that the proposed edit actually corrects apparently erroneous code.  You should be using `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` in this case.  The value (0) is equivalent to `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut` (0<<16) but will fail if you change it to other animation curves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel UIView block-based animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569943/how-to-cancel-uiview-block-based-animation)

Comment: I believe that the best way in 2018 would be to use UIViewPropertyAnimator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: prefer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21527129/194309 from Borut Tomazin

Comment: Documentation states that this method does nothing outside of an animation block

Answer (score 13):

**From Apple docs:** *Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. Instead, you should use the* `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` *method to specify your animations and the animation options.:*

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
} completion:NULL];
```

Comment: thanks alot! that worked, whereas solution by @Thunder Rabbit didn't do it on iOS 7.1. Apple was right after all )

Answer (score 11):

First of all you have to add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction to option like..

```
- (void) fadeImageView {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                         self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //make the image view un-tappable.
                         //if the fade was canceled, set the alpha to 1.0
                     }];

}
```

and then make a method like this....

```
-(void)stopAnimation {
    [self.routeView.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

after that when you want to remove your animation call above method using .....

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Hope it will help you

Happy coding.........!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

EDIT:

Thanks user1244109 to guide me for this.

For iOS7 we have to add one more option `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             self.imageView.alpha = 0.0f;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             //make the image view un-tappable.
                             //if the fade was canceled, set the alpha to 1.0
                         }];
```

Comment: this code worked for me on ios 7 only after specifying `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option too. Edit it if you wish so.