# How to Handle Overlapping Animation Calls in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, animatewithduration

I have a footer bar which is essentially a view containing a button and an image. When a particular button is pressed the function:

- Hides the image (footerImg)
- The button (footerBtn) has text (textToDisplay) added to it
- Then the animation fades the footerBtn out and the image back in
- The entire animation takes about 2 seconds

**My problem**

My problem is that sometimes the user is going to hit the button again before 2 seconds goes by and the same animation will be asked to run before it is finished.  How do I enable my code to handle overlapping animations? I want the second press to stop the first animation and simply run the second animation.

**My Code**

With the code below a second button press ruins the animation and the text AND image both disappear for two seconds and then it goes back to the original state.

```
    //Animate TaskAction feedback in footer bar
    func animateFeedback(textToDisplay: String, footerBtn: UIButton, footerImg: UIImageView) {

    //Cancel any running animation
    footerBtn.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    //Set to defaults - In case it is interrupting animation
    footerBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    footerBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 55/255.0, green: 55/255.0, blue: 55/255.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal) //light gray

    //Setup for animation
    footerImg.alpha = 0.0
    footerBtn.alpha = 1
    footerBtn.setTitle(textToDisplay, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    footerBtn.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", size: 18)

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(2.0 /*Total*/, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear, animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration:0.50, animations:{
            footerBtn.alpha = 0.01 //Text fades out
        })

        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.50, relativeDuration:0.50, animations:{
            footerImg.alpha = 1 //Starting image reappears
        })
    },
    completion: { finished in
        footerBtn.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        footerBtn.alpha = 1
    })//End of animation
}//End of animateFeedback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution:

If an animation gets messed up because a second animation call is triggered before the first animation has finished, read the answer to this post:

[Consecutive Animation Calls Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449016/consecutive-animation-calls-not-working)

Essentially, it has to do with the completion block. Oddly enough, the completion still runs on the 1st animation even if it is interrupted. What you can do is add an if-statement to skip the rest of the completion block if the code didn't finish.