# CoreData Object Move Between Entities Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I have two entities and they have the exact same three attributes (name, desc, displayOrder), both have a handful of records, and my goal is to add/insert every item from "Entity 1" into "Entity 2".

**Close, But No Cigar**

I think my code is quite close. The console print out shows my code is successfully sending each item in "Entity 1" to "Entity 2" and saving it. BUT they save over each other! The first item is moved and saved, then the second item is moved but copies over the item that was previously moved. End result: only the last item moved actually shows up in the final "Entity 2".

**Question**: How do I fix this?

```
@IBAction func testOutMoveList(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Setup 'Do Later' context
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let new_Ent2_Item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity2", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //Get sorted CoreData list and assign it to targetList_Cntxt
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity2")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayOrder", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ sortDescriptor ]
    do {
        let fetchedResults = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]

        if let results = fetchedResults {
            entity2_Cntxt = results
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    for i in 0..<entity1.count {
        //Grab a Today task item
        let itemToMove = entity1_Cntxt[i]

        //Assign the Today item's contents to variables
        let nameToTransfer = itemToMove.valueForKey("name") as? String
        let descToTransfer = itemToMove.valueForKey("desc") as? String
        //Assign the Today item's contents to the target's 'task' object
        new_Ent2_Item.setValue(nameToTransfer, forKey: "name")
        new_Ent2_Item.setValue(descToTransfer, forKey: "desc")

        //Insert the item!!
        entity2_Cntxt.insert(new_Ent2_Item, atIndex: 0)
    }

//Updates target list in Core Data after append, delete, and drag/drop
func update_TargetDisplayOrder() {
    for i in 0..<entity2_Cntxt.count {
        let item = entity2_Cntxt[i]
        item.setValue( i, forKey: "displayOrder" )
    }
}
```

**Possible Clue**: I have noticed that the displayOrder doesn't seem to be updating correctly. The first item should be 0, the second should be 1, etc but instead each time the code cycles the lowest displayOrder is 1 higher (A three item list might start with values 2,3,4 - then my code moves/copies another item to entity 2 and the display order values are: 3,4,5)

**Question**: What code can I add or fix to make this transfer I'm attempting work!?!

**Bonus question:** Post-transfer how do I quickly/easily clear all the values from "Entity 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to move this line:

```
let new_Ent2_Item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity2", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
```

so that it is *inside* the for loop:

```
for i in 0..<entity1.count {
    //Grab a Today task item
    let itemToMove = entity1_Cntxt[i]
    // Create the corresponding new Entity2 object:
    let new_Ent2_Item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Entity2", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    //Assign the Today item's contents to variables
    let nameToTransfer = itemToMove.valueForKey("name") as? String
    let descToTransfer = itemToMove.valueForKey("desc") as? String
    //Assign the Today item's contents to the target's 'task' object
    new_Ent2_Item.setValue(nameToTransfer, forKey: "name")
    new_Ent2_Item.setValue(descToTransfer, forKey: "desc")

    //Insert the item!!
    entity2_Cntxt.insert(new_Ent2_Item, atIndex: 0)
}
```

To explain: the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` is what actually creates the new Entity2 object.  In its original position, that line is run only once, so only one Entity2 object is created.  Your `for` loop then changes its attribute values and inserts it at the start of the `entity2_Cntxt` array (multiple times).  Note that the last step in the `for` loop, `entity2_Cntxt.insert(new_Ent2_Item, atIndex: 0)` does not create a new object, or copy `new_Ent2_Item`, it just inserts it at the start of the array.  With the amended code, a new Entity2 object will be created each time through the loop.

Regarding the `displayOrder` problem, if you inspect the `entity2_Cntxt` array each time through the loop, you should find (with your original code) that the array contains the same Entity2 object several times, followed by the objects obtained from the fetch.  Suppose `entity2_Cntxt` contains the new object three times (at indexes 0,1,2).  Your `update_TargetDisplayOrder` method will then set that object's `displayOrder` to 0, then 1, then 2.  And then the objects returned by the fetch will have `displayOrder` 3, 4, etc.  I think this should all come good when you move the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` as above.

Comment: Wow, that was the quickest solution I've ever implemented. Works great. You were dead-on about the sort order problem too, that now gets the results that it should. THANK YOU

Comment: I don't mean to be rude by asking more of you but you've been really helpful on a lot of my posts and I was wondering if you know anything about animation? I have an animation interruption problem no one has been able to solve and I'd be really grateful if you have any insights http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449016/consecutive-animation-calls-not-working