# Trouble restraining subview's animation within an animation block

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uianimation

**Why restrain a subview from animation? Why not simply carry out its layout changes after the animation?**

That's logical but not feasible considering my view hierarchy and this particular use-case.

My view hierarchy:

MyViewController: `UIViewController` -> MyCustomView: `UIView` -> MyCustomScrollView: `UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource`

Why is it not possible?:

1) I do this in MyViewController after various constraint changes:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

2) Since MyCustomView is a subview which contains MyCustomScrollView (***which in turn contains a UICollectionView as its subview***), the layout update triggers CV's `willDisplay` delegate method under which I'm adding a bunch of labels to MyCustomView, to be precise.

Here's the function in MyCustomView that I'm calling:

```
func addLabel(forIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var label: UILabel!
    label.frame = Util.labelFrame(forIndex: indexPath, fillWidth: false) // The frame for the label is generated here!

    //Will assign text and font to the label which are unnecessary to this context

    self.anotherSubView.addSubview(label) //Add the label to MyCustomView's subview
}
```

3) Since these changes get caught up within the animation block from point 1, I get some unnecessary, undesired animations happening. And so, MyCustomView's layout change is bound with this animation block, forcing me to look for a way to restrain this from happening

**Things tried so far:**

1) Tried the wrap the `addSubView()` from `addLabel(forIndexPath:)` inside a `UIView.performWithoutAnimation {}` block. - No luck

2) Tried the wrap the `addSubView()` from `addLabel(forIndexPath:)` inside another animation block with 0.0 seconds time as to see if this overrides the parent animation block - No luck

3) Explored `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(enabled:)` but it seems like this won't cancel/pause the existing animators, and will completely disable *all the animations* if true (which is not what I want)

**To sum this all up, my problem is:**

I need to restrain the animations on MyCustomView but I need all my other desired layout changes to take place. Is this even possible? Would really appreciate a hint or a solution, TYIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9676508/9293498) answer, removing all the animations from `anotherSubview`'s layer(inside the `addLabel(forIndexPath:)`) after adding the label:

```
self.anotherSubview.addSubview(label)
self.anotherSubview.layer.removeAllAnimations() //Doing this removes the animations queued to animate the label's frame into the view
```

does exactly what I want!